# New relic setup for C# console Application

Tags: c#, .net, newrelic

I have some C# Console applications which have been configured to be run in Windows Task Scheduler. How can I setup new relic for these applications?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/getting-started/introduction-new-relic-net

Answer (score 1):

You will need to

> enable the **Instrument All .NET Applications** feature

See: [Instrument non-IIS apps](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/instrumentation/instrument-non-iis-apps) for additional requirements and information.

Answer (score 0):

A better link:

- https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/transactions/intro-transactions/monitor-background-processes-other-non-web-transactions/

"Monitor Background Processes and other non-web applications" such as console applications

> This document explains what non-web transactions are in APM, and how
> you can instrument background tasks and other arbitrary activity to be
> reported as non-web transactions.
>
> What are non-web transactions? The two main APM transaction categories
> are web and non-web.
>
> Web transactions are transactions we detect as being initiated by a
> web request; they are the most common type of transaction reported by
> APM. Non-web transactions are transactions where we do not detect they
> were initiated by a web request. This includes processes and jobs that
> do not handle web requests, such as message processing and background
> tasks. For example, you might schedule something to run periodically
> on your server to do database work, send emails, etc. The source is
> not a web request but something on your server.
>
> Some non-web transactions from supported frameworks or services are
> detected automatically by New Relic; others may be created using
> custom instrumentation. We intentionally separate your web and non-web
> transactions in the UI.

Link to the .NET page for custom instrumentation:

- https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/net-agent/custom-instrumentation/introduction-net-custom-instrumentation/

Of which the easiest implementation is to use the `[Transaction]` attribute:

- https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/net-agent/custom-instrumentation/custom-instrumentation-attributes-net/